# How to copy a folder containing absolute symlinks and preserve their relative targets

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, symlink

Suppose I have a folder: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wxcrafter` containing some library files and their corresponding symlinks, e.g:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wxcrafter/lib1.so.0 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wxcrafter/lib1.so.0.0.0`

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wxcrafter/lib2.so.0 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wxcrafter/lib2.so.0.0.0`

I want to make a copy of `wxcrafter` to a new location `codeblocks`, *preserving the relative location of the symlink targets*:

`usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/codeblocks/lib1.so.0 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/codeblocks/lib1.so.0.0.0`

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/codeblocks/lib2.so.0 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/codeblocks/lib2.so.0.0.0`

How do I do this on the command line, given that there may be a number of such symlinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [symlinks](https://github.com/brandt/symlinks) program to convert your absolute symlinks into relative ones:

```
symlinks -c  wxcrafter
```

then copy the entire directory:

```
cp -a wxcrafter codeblocks
```

If you *must* use absolute symlinks (but why would you?), make a copy of the original directory before running `symlinks` and restore it after you're done.

The copy (`codeblocks`) will have relative links, if you need them absolute you'll have to write a little script (using `ln -fs $(pwd)/$(readlink $l) $l` to convert any symlink `$l` from relative to absolute), as `symlinks` only converts in one direction. But, again, why bother?

Comment: Thank you for the question correction BTW.  In your response you should have written If not It.